# How to move an audio file from html5 audio element to a type file inputfield?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, file-upload

I have a generated audio element that can play the audio. I also have a form where I can upload files. How can I move the file from the audio element to the inputfield?

**Why do I want to do this ?**

I am using the angular-audio-recorder library. It gives me the functionality to record audio and then play/download this generated audio track. I can first download this recorded audio and then upload it manually afterwards, but I am trying to skip this step by automatically moving the audio to the file input field.

**Generated html 5 audio element:**

```
<audio type="audio/mp3" id="recorded-audio-mainAudio" src="pathofaudio"></audio>
```

**inputfield ready to submit a file:**

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" class="custom-file-upload">
```

*I was already able to get the path out of the audio element with some javascript :*

```
var songPath = document.getElementsById("recorded-audio-mainAudio").src;
```

Comment: _Not possible..For obvious reason_

Comment: So I will always have to download the generated audio first and then upload it aftwerwards?

Comment: If it belongs to your server, why are you uploading it again ?

Comment: I am using the angular-audio-recorder library. It gives me the functionality to record audio and then play/download this audio track. The audio is not on my server, it is generated by this library. I can first download this recorded audio and then upload it manually afterwards, but i was trying to skip this step by automatically moving the audio to the file input field.

Comment: I doubt that is possible.. Let us wait for others input...

Comment: Well it will definitely improve the usability of my application. So it would be awesome if there is a way.